# How to toggle chevron down/up using attr, basesd on sibling toggle states?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to have the span in the ahref rotate on click of it, and rotate it back to it's normal chevron down when the ul its targetting is hidden again.

here is my code (it is shopify, based on liquid loops, so here is the jquery and one of the sets of values, there are 3 more divs in the loop that I excluded) - I have the toggle of the ul (box) to show/hide, but now I just need to add/remove the class of "active-1" to toggle the chevron-down to rotate with css - however I can't seem to achieve this, on click it doesn't remove the class of "active-1" on the span when clicking on another .toggle value.

any guidance would be helpful. thank you!

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('.toggle').on('click', function(){
var targetBox = $(this).attr('target-box'); // Find the target box



    $('.box').not(targetBox).removeClass('shown'); 

    $(targetBox).toggleClass('shown'); // Toggle the current state of this one

  });
});
```

```
<div class="content-group">



    <a href="#" target-box="#box1" class="toggle js-no-transition">Color&nbsp;<span class="chevron-down"></span></a>
       <div class="box-wrapper">
      <ul class="box shown" id="box1">

            <li><label>Black

              <input type="checkbox" name="Color" value="Color_Black">

            </label></li>

            <li><label>Gold

              <input type="checkbox" name="Color" value="Color_Gold">

            </label></li>


            <li><label>Silver

              <input type="checkbox" name="Color" value="Color_Silver">

            </label></li>


      </ul>
       </div>

       </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.toggle').on('click', function() {
       var targetBox = $(this).attr('target-box');
       $('.box').not(targetBox).removeClass('shown');
       $(targetBox).toggleClass('shown');
       $(".chevron-down.active-1").not($(this).find(".chevron-down")).removeClass("active-1");
       $(this).find(".chevron-down").toggleClass("active-1");
    });
 });
```

Comment: @CCodes Glad that I was able to help :)